# configure: error: Please reinstall the libzip distribution

Tags: php, php-7, pecl

I am getting this error, when trying to install Zip for PHP 7:

```
pecl install zip
```

yields the error

> configure: error: Please reinstall the libzip distribution

I did not find anything related to this error.

I tried `apt-get install libzip` but the package was not found.

Answer (score 270, accepted):

**Solved it**:

```
apt-get install libzip-dev
```

will install the missing libzip-distribution

Comment: Note you can do `apt-cache search libzip` or `apt-cache search zip` to do a search for potential installation names. Pipe it through `less` if it comes back with a lot of results, so you can scroll through slowly.

Comment: For CentOS users: `yum -y install libzip-devel`

Comment: This gives me `E: Unable to locate package libzip-dev` also

Answer (score 12):

This might be helpful for webmin/virtualmin users running CentOS 7:

```
 yum install php-pecl-zip
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, tried everything and nothing would install / enable zip for me.

Comment: Life saver! Been trying to solve this for a week...

Comment: Didn't work:

~~~
[root@host ~]# yum install php-pecl-zip
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 185.125.185.32
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 185.125.185.32
 * cpanel-plugins: 185.125.185.32
 * base: mirrors.rit.edu
 * extras: forksystems.mm.fcix.net
 * updates: mirror.cs.pitt.edu
No package php-pecl-zip available.
Error: Nothing to do
~~~

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me with Amazon Linux:

```
yum install libzip-devel.x86_64
```

Answer (score 3):

At the time of this writing, I had to use libzip > = 0.11.  The libzip/libzip-devel package on the official
CentOS x86_64 repository is still on 0.10.  To get around this, the Psychotic Ninja Plus x86_64 repository offers a 0.11 version.  Information for [libzip](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/psychotic-ninja-plus-x86_64/libzip-0.11.2-6.el7.psychotic.x86_64.rpm.html) and [libzip-devel](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/psychotic-ninja-plus-x86_64/libzip-devel-0.11.2-6.el7.psychotic.x86_64.rpm.html) on the Psychotic Ninja Plus repositories can be found on those links.

To install and use this version, you can run the following commands,

Download latest psychotic-release rpm from
`http://packages.psychotic.ninja/7/plus/x86_64/RPMS/`

Install psychotic-release rpm:

```sh
rpm -Uvh psychotic-release*rpm
```

Install libzip-devel rpm package:

```sh
yum --enablerepo=psychotic-plus install libzip-devel
```

Comment: This worked for me on CentOS. Had to download and install both libzip-0.11.2-6.el7.psychotic.x86_64.rpm and libzip-devel-0.11.2-6.el7.psychotic.x86_64.rpm

Comment: I already had 0.10 installed, I had to remove it before configure would recognize the new files:
sudo yum remove libzip;
sudo yum localinstall /var/tmp/libzip-0.11.2-6.el7.psychotic.x86_64.rpm;
sudo yum localinstall /var/tmp/libzip-devel-0.11.2-6.el7.psychotic.x86_64.rpm; 
sudo yum install php-common

Answer (score 2):

Since it took me some time and research to figure this out i think it may come handy for mac-users:

You can install libzip through brew using:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

And then:

```
brew install libzip
```