# How to install MAMP PHP zip extension on masOS Big Sur - M1 arch?

Tags: php, homebrew, pecl, apple-m1, libzip

I'm trying to install php zip module on my new Macbook M1, by using:

```
pecl install zip
```

After a while i'm getting this error:

```
configure: error: Please reinstall the libzip distribution
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/zip/configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.15/bin/php-config' failed
```

So i run:

```
brew install libzip
```

And i get:

```
Warning: libzip 1.7.3 is already installed and up-to-date.
```

At this point i'm stucked. Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [configure: error: Please reinstall the libzip distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45775877/configure-error-please-reinstall-the-libzip-distribution)

Comment: None of them are available with brew for osx

Comment: First run this `xcode-select --install` and then try to install libzip developer package

Comment: Even after that it's not getting installed you'll need to build it from source. Reference to install developer packages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749530/brew-install-zlib-devel-on-mac-os-x-mavericks

Comment: `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`

I tried to build libzip from source also, but after launching ./configure i still get:
`checking for libzip... not found.. configure: error: Please reinstall the libzip distribution`

Comment: You tried building `zip` from source or `libzip`?

Comment: remove libzip distribution and build libzip from source so that it will build and install developer dependencies for php zip extension

Comment: Could you help me understand how to install libzip-devel for osx? I already managed to compile libzip from source

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233899/discussion-between-andrea-lunelio-and-haridarshan).

Comment: Since you've managed to build to libzip, `pecl install zip` should work now

Comment: Unfortunately no, same message `checking for libzip... not found
configure: error: Please reinstall the libzip distribution
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/zip/configure --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.15/bin/php-config' failed`

Comment: What is OS X version?

Comment: Also, please share the command you've used to build libzip

Comment: macOs 11.4.. to build libzip: `mkdir build && cd build`  `cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/libzip`  `make && make install`

Comment: Have you created the symbolic links as you've installed libzip in other folder https://noknow.info/it/os/install_libzip_from_source#sec4

Comment: I set symbolic links for /bin and /include. Files /lib/*.so are not present in my installation folder, i have *.dylib only files

Comment: Now when i run `pecl install zip` it doesn't find any available release

Comment: That's weird, I've build libzip from source on Fedora 33 and installed zip and worked smoothly... Only change was `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..`

Comment: ok get the zip source tar and build that too

Comment: what do you mean? i already built from zip source tar [https://libzip.org/download/libzip-1.8.0.tar.xz]

Comment: I mean download the php zip extension source tar and build that extension

Comment: Downloaded v1.19.3, run `./configure` and get always `checking for libzip... not found configure: error: Please reinstall the libzip distribution` :(

Comment: first get `php-config` path via `which php-config`, second `phpize && ./configure --with-php-config=path of php-config --with-libzip=/usr/local/libzip`, third `make && make install`

Comment: I've modified the `./configure` command add `--with-libzip`

Comment: Finally it compiled, added php.so extension to php.ini but unfortunately when i try to load the library i get this error:
`PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'zip.so' (tried: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.15/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/zip.so (dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.15/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/zip.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.15/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/zip.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture`

Comment: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.15/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/zip.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture), /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.15/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/zip.so.so (dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.15/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/zip.so.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: What is the output of `file <path of php binary file>` _e.g. `file /opt/remi/php80/root/usr/bin/php`_

Comment: If the binary is `32-bit` instead of `64-bit`, then recompile php zip extension `./configure CFLAGS="-arch i386" --with-php-config=path of php-config --with-libzip=/usr/local/libzip`

Comment: Output is `Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`
I'm on a new M1 Macbook with silicon chip

Comment: Can you please check the output of `file <path to zip.so>`?

Comment: This is the output my friend `Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64`

Comment: Ok issue is `zip` extension is build for architecture `arm64` whereas `php` is using `x86_64` architecture, so it's giving `wrong architecture` error. Before rebuilding `zip` extension check `libzip` is build for `x86_64` or `arm64` using `file` utility, if it is build for `arm64` then you'll need to rebuild libzip as well for `x86_64` and then will have to rebuild `zip` extension. Here is the configure command for php `zip` extension `./configure CFLAGS="-arch x86_64" --with-php-config=path of php-config --with-libzip=/usr/local/libzip`

Comment: So i recompiled libzip with command `cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/libzip -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=x86_64` and then zip with `phpize && ./configure CFLAGS="-arch x86_64"  --with-php-config=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.15/bin/php-config --with-libzip=/usr/local/libzip`
Zip.so generated and `file .../zip.so` output is `Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64`
Yet the library is not working, same wrong architecture error of before. Damn!

Comment: In /usr/local/libzip/lib i have different versions of libzip.*.dylib and they all are x86_64 except for `libzip.5.3.dylib` that is still arm64. Could this be the issue?

Comment: Yes that could be the issue. This should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/1439989/2324206