# dockerizing Laravel + vue

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, docker, vue.js

Trying to migrate my Laravel and Vue code into docker but I am getting an error building the Image

This is my docker file

```
# dockerfile
    FROM php:8-fpm

    # Copy composer.lock and composer.json
    COPY ./composer.lock* ./composer.json* /var/www/

    # Set working directory
    WORKDIR /var/www

    # Install dependencies
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        libpng-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        locales \
        zip \
        jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
        unzip \
        curl

    # Clear cache
    RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*



    # Install extensions
    #RUN apt-get install -y libzip-dev zlib1g-dev
    RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql  zip gd pcntl opcache bcmath
    #RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
    RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
    RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
    RUN pecl install -o -f redis \
        &&  rm -rf /tmp/pear \
        &&  docker-php-ext-enable redis

    # Install composer
    RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

    # NPM for frontend builds
    #RUN apt install nodejs npm -y

    RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash -

    #RUN apt-get install nodejs -y

    # Add user for laravel application
    RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
    RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

    # Copy existing application directory contents
    COPY ./corambackend /var/www

    # Copy existing application directory permissions
    COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www
    
    #COPY httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

    # Change current user to www
    USER www

    # Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
    EXPOSE 80
    CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

and the error I'm getting is

```
#10 37.43 checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20210902
#10 37.43 checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
#10 37.43 checking if debug is enabled... no
#10 37.44 checking if zts is enabled... no
#10 37.46 checking for gawk... no
#10 37.46 checking for nawk... nawk
#10 37.46 checking if nawk is broken... no
#10 37.46 checking for zip archive read/write support... yes, shared
#10 37.47 checking for libzip >= 0.11 libzip != 1.3.1 libzip != 1.7.0... no
#10 37.47 configure: error: Package requirements (libzip >= 0.11 libzip != 1.3.1 libzip != 1.7.0) were not met:
#10 37.47
#10 37.47 No package 'libzip' found
#10 37.47 No package 'libzip' found
#10 37.47 No package 'libzip' found
#10 37.47
#10 37.47 Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
#10 37.47 installed software in a non-standard prefix.
#10 37.47
#10 37.47 Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBZIP_CFLAGS
#10 37.47 and LIBZIP_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
#10 37.47 See the pkg-config man page for more details.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql  zip gd pcntl opcache bcmath]: exit code: 1
```

I try adding

```
    RUN apt-get install -y \
            libzip-dev \
            zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip
```

but it did not work. If anyone can help out with the docker file or can point me to a good resource do dockerizing Laravel + vue with php 8.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [configure: error: Please reinstall the libzip distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45775877/configure-error-please-reinstall-the-libzip-distribution). The `No package 'libzip' found` error is pretty self-describing.

Comment: Did you make sure you tried the apt-get  part for libzip before the first RUN statement in your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that you cleared all the cache in apt, you need to add the line `RUN apt-get update` again to install the package.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libzip-dev \
        zip \
&& docker-php-ext-install zip
```